# How to add input to parsing exceptions in json4s?

Tags: json, scala, parsing, exception, json4s

Suppose I am parsing JSON with `json4s`.

```
val jv = org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse(json) // json is any JsonInput
```

The `parse` may raise exceptions. Unfortunately those exceptions don't contain the input (`json`) and sometimes I cannot understand and reproduce them.

I can wrap the `parse` with a wrapper (see below) but it doesn't work

```
try org.json4s.native.JsonMethods.parse(json) catch { 
  case e: Exception => throw new MyParseException(json, e)
}
```

Now what if `json` is an `InputStream` ? Should I read the stream ? What if the JSON is very large ? I probably don't need the *whole* stream. I need just the part of it up to the character where the `parse` failed.

How would you suggest add the input to the parsing exceptions ?